# Getting the contents of an inner table to center

Tags: html, css

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WayneCa/gzw2t5fL/29/) with the code. I know the issue is with the CSS, but I am not proficient enough with CSS to know what I'm doing wrong. The only thing that isn't right is the contents of the inner table not being centered within the table, specifically the link text at the top and the associated image below it.

If you remove the outer table it centers as it should. I included the -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1; property so the size of the image would be there since the image is not. I don't know the equivalent properties to add to make that happen on other browsers.

The CSS:

```
  body {
    margin:0;
    background-image:url('Images/big1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:black;
    color:aliceblue;
    font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:12pt;
  }
  a {
    color:mediumspringgreen;
  }
  table {
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:colseplapse;
  }
  .table2 {
    border:1px solid silver;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border-spacing:0;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
  }
  .table3 {
    border:1px solid silver;
    padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;
    border-spacing:0;
  }
  .thead {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: auto;
  }
  .tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 34em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .tbody tr {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: auto;
  }
  .td1 {
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:springgreen;
  }
  .img {
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1;
    width:162px;
    height:116px;
  }
  .bottom {vertical-align:bottom;}
  .center {text-align:center;}
  .bold {font-weight:bold;}
  .bolder {font-weight:900;}
```

The HTML:

```
<TABLE class='table2'>
  <THEAD class='thead'>
  </THEAD>
  <TBODY class='tbody'>
    <TR>
      <TH class='td1 table3'>
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
          <TH colspan=5><A href='R1_Jula.html' target='new'>Region 1:<BR>Jula<BR><BR><IMG class='img bottom' src='GreatCrystal/Jula_Thumb.PNG' alt='Region 1: Jula'></A></TH>
          </TR><TR>
            <TD class='center bold'><A href='GreatCrystal/Jula_Front.PNG' target='new' title='Region 1, Jula: Front View'>Front View</A></TD>
            <TH class='bolder'>|</TH>
            <TD class='center bold'><A href='GreatCrystal/Jula_Side.PNG' target='new' title='Region 1, Jula: Side View'>Side View</A></TD>
            <TH class='bolder'>|</TH>
            <TD class='center bold'><A href='GreatCrystal/Jula_Top.PNG' target='new' title='Region 1, Jula: Top View'>Top View</A></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TH>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong and corrected it. The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WayneCa/gzw2t5fL/29/) confirms it works now. The code is revised as follows:

CSS

```
  body {
    margin:0;
    background-image:url('../Images/big1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:black;
    color:aliceblue;
    font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:12pt;
  }
  a {
    color:mediumspringgreen;
  }
  table {
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  .table2 {
    border:1px solid silver;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border-spacing:0;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
  }
  .table3 {
    border:1px solid silver;
    padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;
    border-spacing:0;
  }
  .thead {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: auto;
  }
  .tbody {
    display: block;
    table-layout:fixed;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 34em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .td1 {
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:springgreen;
  }
  .center {text-align:center;}
  .bold {font-weight:bold;}
  .bolder {font-weight:900;}
  .img {
    display: block;
    table-layout:fixed;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:18%;
    margin-right:18%;
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1;
    width:162px;
    height:116px;
  }
```

HTML

```
    <TABLE class='table2'>
      <THEAD class='thead'>
      </THEAD>
      <TBODY class='tbody'>
      <TR>
        <TD class='td1 table3' style='border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-left:none'>
          <TABLE>
            <TR>
              <TH colspan=5 class='center'><A href='R1_Jula.html' target='new'>Region 1:<BR>Jula<BR><BR><IMG class='img border0 bottom' src='GreatCrystal/JulaThumb.png' alt='Region 1: Jula'></A></TH>
            </TR><TR>
              <TD class='center bold'><A href='GreatCrystal/JulaFront.png' target='new' title='Region 1, Jula: Front View'>Front View</A></TD>
              <TH class='bolder'>|</TH>
              <TD class='center bold'><A href='GreatCrystal/JulaSide.png' target='new' title='Region 1, Jula: Side View'>Side View</A></TD>
              <TH class='bolder'>|</TH>
              <TD class='center bold'><A href='GreatCrystal/JulaTop.png' target='new' title='Region 1, Jula: Top View'>Top View</A></TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```